# Problem creating "Customer Community Login" users in one Summer '21 org

Tags: community, customer-community, lightning-community, user-management, self-registration

Salesforce provided us with a Summer '21 org early this week but it had no "Customer Community Login" licenses provisioned so we had to get those added via a case.

As a System Administrator, using the "Enable Customer User" button on a Contact and filling in the appropriate license and profile in the "New User" page, the "Save" results in:

> Insufficient Privileges You do not have the level of access necessary
> to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of
> the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more
> information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.
>
> Click here to return to the previous page.

with nothing in the debug log.

As a Site Guest User, using a self registration page that works fine in other orgs, this error results:

> insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

with the debug log having the expected logging up to the point that the `Site.createExternalUser` call is made.

Any ideas on what the problem is here? Or what to double check?

(Hoping some step was missed by Salesforce in the org setup here...)

Comment: Is your "System Administrator" profile listed in the profiles for the community?

Comment: Also, if you use a different license type for a profile associated with the community, does it work?

Comment: Hi Phil, Yes to the SA profile question. And also cloning a second profile that is not linked to any community and trying to register (as the SA) results in the same failure. Will try e.g. a "plus" license now.

Comment: I assume that the cloned profiles got linked to the community for testing?

Comment: Yes they are set as Members and one is selected as the profile that self-registering users are assigned. Using the "Customer Community Plus Login" license the SA registration works but the self-registration fails as before. Perhaps two different problems here: maybe the "Customer Community Login" license is missing something that has to be set on the Salesforce side and I'm missing something for the self-registration.

Comment: And performing the SA User insert in Apex code in the Developer Console produced INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY. So perhaps that is the one core problem.

Comment: Seems weird... do you have sharing and have you set up any Sharing Sets?

Comment: No. And ran the code through a `without sharing` class too - same error. Think/hope it is an org-specific problem.

Comment: That error (insufficient access on cross reference entity) is really unhelpful because it doesn't include the ID of the entity you have no access to. Very annoying. Leaves you clueless... wish they would fix it.

Comment: Yeah, though presume the argument is security so to not leak an `Id`; but reporting the type would provide important clues. We will probably end up burning multiple days on a case for this problem.

Comment: (Not really convinced an ID is much of a security leak since you must have already had the ID in order to not have sufficient access to it, and can't do anything with it given you have no access to that record... ho hum)